# Ellipsis in the middle of the sentence

Tags: javascript, html, css

I had a situation with our product that in case of text overflow. We needed to cut the text in the middle.

I wanted to use as less JavaScript as possible.
There were some suggestions on the web. most of them included splitting the string into two parts in JavaScript and then use `text-overflow ellipsis` on one side and `text-overflow: clip` on the other side together with `direction:rtl`

This sounded like a good solution for me.
But, when I tried to implement this solution I realized that the right side text can be cut in the middle of the text even in the middle of a specific character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So my problem was that one side was fine. But, the other could have a letter cut in the middle that didn't look good.
So I thought what if I will use ellipsis on both sides. Now, no letter was cut in the middle but I had `...   ...` in the middle of the text.
I say what if I will use negative left margin on the right side. That fixed this issue but when I had a sentence too small for ellipsis the two parts were overlapping each other.
So I made the container `display: flex` added a middle element with a width and `flex-shrink` and tail element with `flex-grow:1`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.part1, .part2 {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;  
  text-overflow: ellipsis;  
  flex-shrink: 1;  
}


.part2 {
  direction: rtl;
  margin-left: -20px
}

.end {
  flex-grow: 1; 
}

.mid{  
  width: 20px;
  flex-shrink: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="part1">This is the first part of the sentence i</div><div class="mid"></div><div class="part2">t is a very long senetense that we want to split</div><div class="end"></div>
</div>
```

Now all you need to do is just cut the sentence into two parts in JavaScript and that's it.
well...
because the right part is `rtl` you will need to fix the `.` - if it is at the start of part2 add it to the end of part1 and if it is at the end of part2 add it to the start of part2.

Comment: Why ask a question if you are going to answer it straight away?

Comment: @VisioN I know you can answer your own question, but why ask it in the first place if you already know the answer?  Usually self answering is for if you have asked a question and then later manage to solve the problem yourself and no one else has answered

Comment: We have the option to answer a question directly when asking the question, I assume OP thinks his issue is relevant for others.

Comment: @Pete Well, I will disagree here. This is how you share your knowledge. If you found a nice solution and you want to show everyone how you've solved it, you can answer your own question and wait if anybody could come up with a better variant. I personally encourage such behaviour.

Comment: @VisioN then OP should ask the question in a manner that will be of aid - ie show the code that wasn't working and also answer with the code in the actual answer rather than just a fiddle link, which as it is saved to their account, may break in future if they decide to delete the fiddle (which I see some kind user has edited the answer for that)